# Bootstrap panel and list not shown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am  try to  show boot strap list group and Panels in my html page but it is not working..

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Report Filling</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="list-group" style="max-width: 200px;">
        <li class="list-group-item">@Html.ActionLink("Upload CTR", "UploadCTR", "Upload")</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@Html.ActionLink("Upload ETR", "UploadETR", "Upload")</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@Html.ActionLink("Upload STR", "UploadSTR", "Upload")</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i go the output like..

[image]

Comment: do you get any `404` error in console?

Comment: are all css files included properly? `href="~/`?

Answer (score 2):

Your source code is perfectly working but you're missing a good link to your CSS as @jyrc753 suggests.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Report Filling</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group" style="max-width: 200px;">
        <li class="list-group-item">@Html.ActionLink("Upload CTR", "UploadCTR", "Upload")</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@Html.ActionLink("Upload ETR", "UploadETR", "Upload")</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@Html.ActionLink("Upload STR", "UploadSTR", "Upload")</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is perfectly working.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/xLmjv/

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC project template automatically creates bundles for bootstrap. Check if they are created correctly and are loaded in your shared _Layout file:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```